# Loop in SQL and increase one field each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Create table for store raw data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[raw_data](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[first_data] [int] NULL,
[next_counts] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID) );
```

Create table for processed data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SplittedAndProcessedData](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[count] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID) );
```

Now store raw data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[raw_data]
(
     [raw_data].[first_data]
    ,[raw_data].[next_counts]
) VALUES
(
    8500   /*first_data*/
    ,'10,2,0,95,15' /*next_counts*/
)
```

I am turning a comma separated string into individual rows:

```
SELECT Splitted_Row.value
FROM [dbo].[raw_data]
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT ([raw_data].[next_counts], ',') Splitted_Row
```

Like this:

| value |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 2 |
| 0 |
| 95 |
| 15 |

I want to insert into `SplittedAndProcessedData` table using a loop, like this:

| ID | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8500 |
| 2 | 8510 |
| 3 | 8512 |
| 4 | 8512 |
| 5 | 8607 |
| 6 | 8622 |

Which means:

1. ID(1) = 8500    --first data
2. ID(2) = 8500 + 10 = 8510
3. ID(3) = 8510 + 2 = 8512
4. ID(4) = 8512 + 0 = 8512
5. ID(5) = 8512 + 95 = 8607
6. ID(6) = 8607 + 15 = 8622

Comment: In expected result, how you want to order your data?

Comment: SQL is a set-oriented language. It doesn't need loops. In this case, what you descrive is a running total based on some random order. The real solution is to *not* store CSVs in a field at all. This is a major design bug that breaks the most fundamental database rule - one cell stores one value

Comment: you cannot get the correct order, see [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), where it says: "The output rows might be in any order"

Comment: You can use the `OVER` clause to calculate a running total, eg `SUM(value) OVER (ORDER By ???)` but you'll have to specify the order of the values somehow. In SQL, there's no implicit order unless it's specified by ORDER BY. You can user `ORDER BY NULL` if you don't care about possibly changing orders

Comment: When saving raw data, we can also insert processed data in the SplittedAndProcessedData table via SCOPE_IDENTITY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a cumulative sum, but using `STRING_SPLIT()` to extract the substring by position is a tricky apporach. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), *the output rows might be in any order* and *the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string*.

But you may try a JSON-based approach to parse the `next_counts` column. You need to transform the data into a valid JSON array (`10,2,0,95,15` into `[10,2,0,95,15]`) and parse this array with `OPENJSON()`. The result from the `OPENJSON()` call is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the `key` column holds the 0-based index of the element in the specified array.

```
-- INSERT INTO SplittedAndProcessedData ([count])
SELECT 
   SUM(data) OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS [count]
FROM (
   SELECT -1 AS rn, first_data AS data
   FROM raw_data r
   UNION ALL
   SELECT CONVERT(int, j.[key]), TRY_CONVERT(int, j.value)
   FROM raw_data r
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', r.next_counts, ']')) j
) t
```

Result (form the `SELECT` part of the statement):

```
count
-----
8500
8510
8512
8512
8607
8622
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function `sum` as follows:

```
SELECT [raw_data].[firstdata] 
       + sum(Splitted_Row.value) 
          over (partition by [raw_data].[id] 
               order by CHARINDEX(',' + Splitted_Row.value + ',', ',' + [raw_data].[next_counts] + ',')
FROM [dbo].[raw_data]
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT ([raw_data].[next_counts], ',') Splitted_Row
```